# TypeError: lambda.invoke is not a function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to call an aws lambda function within another lambda function. I tried a very simple code snippet. However, every time I am receiving "TypeError: lambda.invoke is not a function".

Here is my code:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.apiVersions = {
      lambda: '2015-03-31',
      // other service API versions
    };

    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

    var params = {
        FunctionName: "node-sendsms", 
        InvocationType: "Event", 
        LogType: "Tail", 
        Payload: null
    };

    lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
};
```

I referred to the documentation here for invoke function: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property
and followed same code. I tried changing api version but that did not help. I also tried looking out for any solution online as well as on SO; at least information I got is that it can be an issue of variable scoping for AWS variable. But, as it can be seen in code - it does not seems like that.

Any experts on this error? I am working on node.js 6.10. Here is error detail:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 849581c1-d669-11e7-ad15-6f5e52f0e184 Process exited before completing request"
}

Request ID:
"849581c1-d669-11e7-ad15-6f5e52f0e184"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 849581c1-d669-11e7-ad15-6f5e52f0e184 Version: $LATEST
2017-12-01T07:30:35.785Z    849581c1-d669-11e7-ad15-6f5e52f0e184    TypeError: lambda.invoke is not a function
    at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:22:9)
END RequestId: 849581c1-d669-11e7-ad15-6f5e52f0e184
REPORT RequestId: 849581c1-d669-11e7-ad15-6f5e52f0e184  Duration: 1385.62 ms    Billed Duration: 1400 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB  
RequestId: 849581c1-d669-11e7-ad15-6f5e52f0e184 Process exited before completing request
```

Comment: Check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621134/invoke-a-lambda-from-a-node-package-function). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks for help. I tried with both apirelease version 2015-03-31 and 2014-11-11. but, same error.

Comment: Very strange, this looks correct.  Be sure you have `'use strict';` at the beginning of the script -- it might reveal the real nature of the problem.

Comment: still the same error. thx for comment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

install the latest version of aws sdk or mention like

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.apiVersions = {
        lambda: '2015-03-31'  ///ignore if latest version
    };

    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
```

refer https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1823 for more details